# Sorting Array alphabetically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort a NSArray alphabetically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351182/how-to-sort-a-nsarray-alphabetically)

Hi all,
I have an array which consist of companies name. I want to sort array alphabetically so that companies name come in alphabetic order.
Please suggest me how to do this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
[myArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Answer (score 5):

```
NSArray *sortedStrings = [strings sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Answer (score 2):

If the array consists of `NSStrings`:

```
[companies sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```