# How to sort NSComboBox contents

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nsmutablearray, nscombobox

Here is my code to display combo box:

```
self.records = [[NSMutableArray alloc]
                      initWithArray:[mylist componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];
[self.recordsCombo addItemsWithObjectValues:self.records];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You never sort comboBox's items**. In fact you sort the array, which is the data source for the combo box.

As in your case you need to sort the `self.records` and then addItems to combobox.

```
self.records = [[NSMutableArray alloc]
                  initWithArray:[mylist componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];

self.records = [self.records sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

[self.recordsCombo addItemsWithObjectValues:self.records];
```

Comment: Okay, got it. How do you sort without using Descriptors as it only consists of strings? Just wanted to sort alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

Actually sorting alphabetically is covered already here: [Sorting Array alphabetically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107725/sorting-array-alphabetically)

Otherwise you could alway implement your own sorting algorithm, like Quicksort or somewhat like this. Depends on your skills and needs.