# How to sort NSArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort a NSArray alphabetically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351182/how-to-sort-a-nsarray-alphabetically)

I am using below code to load data into UITableView from NSArray.

How can I sort them in alphabetical order ? 
Mine is `NSArray` not `NSMutableArray` nor I am using `Dictionary`

```
defaultVot = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:pathToVot error:&error];

NSString *fileName = [[defaultVot objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1] lastPathComponent];

NSString *filenameWithoutExtension = [fileName substringToIndex:[fileName length] -4];

cell.textLabel.text = filenameWithoutExtension;
```

Comment: Maybe this [link][1] would help.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351182/how-to-sort-a-nsarray-alphabetically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](http://tahabebek.wordpress.com/2011/03/23/how-to-sort-an-nsarray-alphabetically/)

And also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351182/how-to-sort-a-nsarray-alphabetically)

Answer (score 3):

You should probably sort your array earlier. (Likely when you load the list.) Then use the sorted array as the datasource.

```
NSArray * defaultVot = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:pathToVot error:&error];
NSMutableArray * array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[defaultVot count]];
for (NSString * f in defaultVot){
    NSString *fileName = [f lastPathComponent];
    NSString *filenameWithoutExtension = [fileName substringToIndex:[fileName length] -4];
    [array addObject:filenameWithoutExtension];
}
NSArray * sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sortedArray = [yourArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000132-SW5) on how to accomplish this.

As an example:

```
// From the Documentation
sortedArray =
    [anArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

This will return a new array that is sorted using the rules for the current locale (in a case insensitive manner).