# How to sort NSArray of NSStrings using NSPredicate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nspredicate

I have `NSarray` contains the list of Animals. The array contains a list of animals with repeated elements. I have to make an array with distinct values in the array.
Repeated values should be removed using `NSPredicate`.

Here is my Code :-

```
NSArray *arrAnimals = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Cat",@"Rat",@"Fish",@"Cat",@"Fish",@"Cat",@"Cat",@"Bird",@"Fish",@"Cat",@"Frog", nil];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"distinct"]];
arrAnimals = [arrAnimals filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Here I am using "distinct" keyword for sorting the array, but not able to find any solution.
I have preferred many links.

http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/stevez/archive/2013/10/21/ios-objective-c-filtering-a-nsarray-using-nspredicate.aspx

Please resolve my problem.

Comment: Is your goal to remove duplicates, or sort alphabetically? Or both?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351182/how-to-sort-a-nsarray-alphabetically

Comment: Yaah my goal is to remove duplicate entries and sort alphabetically too.

Answer (score 2):

There is no predicate for this, but you can use Key-Value Operator:

```
distinct = [array valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.self"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the keyword "distinctUnionOfObjects.self". This method will also returns sorted array. After removing repeated values.

Comment: It preserves the order, so if your original array is sorted, the result will be too.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove duplicates from an array by creating a set with its objects and converting it back to an array.

```
NSArray *arrAnimals = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Cat",@"Rat",@"Fish",@"Cat",@"Fish",@"Cat",@"Cat",@"Bird",@"Fish",@"Cat",@"Frog", nil];
NSArray *arrayWithoutDuplicates = [[NSSet setWithArray:arrAnimals] allObjects];
```

Comment: This code works for me. This will returns the array of after removing duplicate values, without using NSPredicate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this one with answered by @iMartin

```
 NSArray *arrAnimals = @[@"Cat",@"Rat",@"Fish",@"Cat",@"Fish",@"Cat",@"Cat",@"Bird",@"Fish",@"Cat",@"Frog"];

    arrAnimals= [arrAnimals valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.self"];

    arrAnimals= [arrAnimals sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        unichar firstChar =  [obj1 characterAtIndex:0];
        unichar secondChar =  [obj2 characterAtIndex:0];

        if ( firstChar == secondChar) {
            return NSOrderedSame;
        } else {
            if ( firstChar > secondChar) {
                return NSOrderedDescending;
            } else {
                return NSOrderedAscending;
            }

        }

    }];
```