# How am I able to create a tableViewCell that shows added texts by textfield alphabetically?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, textfield

I added texts into tableViewCell by using a textfield, and the order of words entered in the cell on the top of a tableView was non-alphabetical. How does it become alphabetically ordered? Is there any built-in method to do this, or do I write a method? Thank you!

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!
var stringArray = [String]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return stringArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = stringArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    return true
}

@IBAction func AddButton(sender: UIButton) {
    stringArray.append(myTextField.text)
    myTextField.text = nil
    myTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351182/how-to-sort-a-nsarray-alphabetically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UITableView` is just showing you the same strings that are in your array. You are using the `append` method which always adds the items to the end of the array. Instead you should sort your array and the data shown in the `UITableView` will be sorted.

Arrays have `sort` for which you provide the comparison closure. Either you make a method for sorting and pass it to the `sort` as the `isOrderedBefore` parameter, or you could do it this way.

```
stringArray.sort(){ $0 < $1 }
```

where `$0` and `$1` are the first and second parameters that will be compared.

Comment: You're welcome. If it worked for you, please mark the question as answered so others don't think this is still an open question :)

Answer (score 0):

For a Finder like sort order you can use localizedStandardCompare.

```
    stringArray.sortInPlace { (x, y) -> Bool in
        return x.localizedStandardCompare(y) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
    }
```

Also to add onto @hannad's answer, you should use **sortInPlace** to ensure stringArray is sorted. Else use something like

```
    sortedArray = stringArray.sort(){ $0 < $1 }
```

Comment: I am using Swift1.2. Was `sortInPlace` added in Swift2 or am I just bad at searching for it?

Comment: sorted and sort were replaced by sort and sortInPlace in Swift 2