# How to manually sort NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I read the following link [About sorting NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351182/how-to-sort-a-nsarray-alphabetically)

But I am struggling to convert this to my use case where I need to manually sort based on values that are inside an `NSDictionary` inside an `NSArray`.

I tried to google search for Sort using `NSDictionary` inside `NSArray` but got no good hits. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you want to sort a `NSMutableArray` or `NSArray`? What did you try and what was the result?

Comment: It’s a NSMutableArray that I want sort based on a name that is held in a Dictionary inside the array, I didn’t try anything cause I cannot find any pointers that explains how

Comment: [Sorting Arrays](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000132-SW5)

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy to sort a NSArray of Dictionary

Use

```
 NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Your key" ascending:YES];
 NSArray *sortedArray = [yourUnsortedArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sort]];
```

It will work.

Just change the key name and array name according to you.